# Getting OBJECT and not a string using hashmap

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using some hashmap and wanna in the end of the code takes all values of this hashmap without pass a single key value.

Basic flow:

1. Create hashmap from a external file, structure of the file "id:value"
2. use this hashmap
3. insert new values in hashmap
4. get all keys and values to save in the external file

I'm tried to pass all the map without use get but not work.

```
fs.appendFile('test.txt', this.map.toString(), 'utf8', (err: Error) =>
{
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Data is appended to file successfully.');
});
```

Comment: is `this.map` a JS Map? Or an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `map` is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) then you can serialise it by first converting it to an array of key/pair values.

```
const stringMap = JSON.stringify([...this.map])
```

If it's a plain JS object then `JSON.stringify(this.map)` will suffice